# How to validate hidden input field

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am validating hidden field. when I submit blank entry it validate but message goes at the top of the form. I am trying to show this message to its label fields, but not get success.

Here it the code.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <form method="GET" action="#" style="margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 100px;">
    <label for="test123">Name : </label>
    <input type="text" style="display: none;" value="" required="" name="test123" id="test123">
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("label[for='test123']").click(function(){
        $("#test123").css('display','block');
    });
    </script>
```

Input box will appear after clicking on name label.

Comment: May be I'm wrong according to your requirement but you should use type="hidden" for that.

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com If I apply type="hidden" js stops validating.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hide it just set its opacity to 0.

```
$('#test123').css('opacity','0');
```

and to show it again:

```
$('#test123').css('opacity','1');
```

Comment: Thanks its near to, what I want, but error message is pointing to invisible input field not to the label.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's **.append()** to append your error message into the DOM, next to your desired input field.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(){
if(!isValid()){
var html = "<div style='color:#D50000'>Error</div>";
 $("#test123").append(html).show(); //show() to show the input element
}
});
```

*SideNote*:
Use [Happy.js](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/Happy.js), it's a pretty lightweight, easy to use validation plugin, which will solve your problem.